# Get posts as json via ajax in wordress Beaver Builder

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have written a custom calendar module for use with Beaver Builder.

I want to fetch posts from a custom post_type of 'event' to populate the calendar.

In my beaver builder module I have the following:

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'axios', 'https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'qs', 'https://unpkg.com/qs/dist/qs.js');

function get_ajax_event_calendar_posts() {
// Query Arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('event'),
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'posts_per_page' => 40,
    'nopaging' => true,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'cat' => 1,
);
// The Query
$ajaxposts = get_posts( $args ); // changed to get_posts from wp_query, because `get_posts` returns an array
echo json_encode( $ajaxposts );
wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}


    // Fire AJAX action for both logged in and non-logged in users
add_action('wp_ajax_get_ajax_event_calendar_posts','get_ajax_event_calendar_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ajax_event_calendar_posts', 'get_ajax_event_calendar_posts');
```

and in my modules JavaScript (frontend.php) I have:

```js
    var data = { action: "get_ajax_event_calendar_posts" };

     axios.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>", Qs.stringify(data))
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

I have one post in 'event'. In the browser, I test the endpoint by visiting `xxx.flywheelsites.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_ajax_event_calendar_posts` and receive an empty array `[]`. I expect to receive a single event. I've looked in the admin and can see the post.

When clicking on the button in my module to make the Ajax request, I receive a `400 error`

Checking the logs, I receive the following error message:

`(MISSING)127.0.0.1 -  04/Jan/2020:16:41:40 +0000 "POST /.wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 400 /www/.wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 64263000 4103576 709.963 4096 35.21%!`

This error message doesn't really tell me anything. I also altered my axios method to use a `GET` - however, I receive the same error.

Any advice on how I can debug this would be really helpful. Thanks!

Wordpress, Astra Theme, Beaver Builder, hosted on flywheel.

** Edit **

To test, in my `get_ajax_event_calendar_posts` method I am echo'ing out 'hello world'

```
function get_ajax_event_calendar_posts() {
    // Query Arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('event'),
        'post_status' => array('publish'),
        'posts_per_page' => 40,
        'nopaging' => true,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'cat' => 1,
    );
    // The Query
    $ajaxposts = get_posts( $args ); // changed to get_posts from wp_query, because `get_posts` returns an array
    echo 'hello world'; //json_encode( $ajaxposts );
    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

I visit the url in my browser and see 'hello world' - so it seems there might be a problem in querying the data? The logs don't contain anything useful. However, from this I can see I can hit the route and get a response from it.

** Edit **

I can now view the posts when hitting the url directly. Appears to be an issue of cacheing.... I have updated my JS - yet the old files persist. I'm hopeful this is just a cacheing issue...

Comment: This should be your answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/302209/get-posts-with-ajax

Comment: @Dilek thanks. I saw that... my code is basically the same - apart from WP_die(). I've swapped my code to use 'exit' etc and it still fails when going directly to the URL (so not using the axios part)

Answer (score 0):

Using Beaver Builder, I had to clear Beaver Builders cache. To clear it, go into `settings -> beaver-builder -> tools` and click the clear cache button.